# Get all <style> tags and concatenate the contents into one <style> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I know I can get the style tag with

`$('style')`

but how can I get all style tags from the document and merge them into a single style block ?

Comment: to clean some html requested trough ajax

Comment: You want to do it at load time, or just once?

Answer (score 4):

```
<script>
var styles;
$("style").each(function(a,b){
    styles = styles + "\n" + b.html();
    $(this).remove();
});

$("#style").html('<style>'+ styles +'</style>');

</script>
<div id="style>

</div>
```

Comment: @LeahSilber: a = index (0,1,2,3,4) and b is content

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can do it in two lines:

```js
// add a new style element before the first one with all the rules
$('style:first').before('<style type="text/css" id="new">'+$('style').text()+'</style>');

// remove all the style elements except the one added above
$("style:not('#new')").remove();
```

[**Here is a demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/KHkx4/) <sup>Updated</sup>